# wcout will not print right single quotation mark

Tags: c++, string, unicode

I am surprised to see that `std::wcout` will not print a *right single quotation mark* in a string and in fact it breaks down. Nothing else is printed after that to the console.

```
std::wcout << L"Parents’s Name";
```

Note that the character in question looks like apostrophe but it's not, it's called *right single quotation mark* which has unicode value of 0x2019.

If I use `cout` instead, it prints wrong character in its place but does print the rest of the string. But I am working with unicode strings so I am interested to know why `wcout` doesn't work.

As you can see this is not really a special/control character and can be part of a string. Is there something I can do about it to get it printed?

Comment: Using the character in the code like that, you need to make sure the file encoding is the same as what the compiler expects. To see if that's the issue, you could try replacing the character with `\u2019` and see how it behaves.

Comment: @aschepler I write this to a file as well where I make sure the encoding is unicode UCS-2 BOM (as per notepad++) but same result. The printing stops at this character, nothing else is written to the file.

Comment: Try `std::wcout << L"Parents’s Name";`.  Notice the "L".

Comment: @MarkRansom I have already tried that, sorry I mistakenly pasting the cout test line I had in code instead of wcout. Will update the post.

Comment: Then I'd try @aschepler's suggestion: `std::wcout << L"Parents\u2019s Name";`

Comment: @MarkRansom Same result with \u2019 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the OS is Windows, set the console mode to support wide characters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"Parents’s Name";
}
```

Output:

```
Parents’s Name
```